# Problemas con select option de html en bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap, bootstrap-4, font-awesome

Tengo un select que me muestra una lista de colores, ya logre colocar los colores en las letras y un icono de fontawesone en cuadrado, pero mi problema viene cuando selecciono un elemento de la lista me pone en negro las letras y también el cuadro como podría hacer para que cuando seleccione me pinte como esta en la lista la letra y el icono del color seleccionado. Gracias. debajo pongo el codigo, estoy usando bootstrap.

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label for="color" class="col-form-label font-weight-bold">Color:</label>                   
                <select class="form-control fa" name="color" id="color" required>
                    <option value="">Seleccionar</option>
                    <option class="fa" style="color:#0071c5;" value="#0071c5">&#xf0c8; Azul Oscuro</option>
                    <option class="fa" style="color:#40E0D0;" value="#40E0D0">&#xf0c8; Turquesa</option>
                    <option class="fa" style="color:#008000;" value="#008000">&#xf0c8; Verde</option>
                    <option class="fa" style="color:#FFD700;" value="#FFD700">&#xf0c8; Amarillo</option>
                    <option class="fa" style="color:#FF8C00;" value="#FF8C00">&#xf0c8; Naranja</option>
                    <option class="fa" style="color:#FF0000;" value="#FF0000">&#xf0c8; Rojo</option>
                    <option class="fa" style="color:#000000;" value="#000000">&#xf0c8; Negro</option>
                </select>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya que el valor de los `options` son el color de cada `option`, puedes usar a esos valores para aplicar el estilo al `select` y cambiarle de color, es decir, si escoges el `option` cuyo valor es el color naranja, ese valor (el color naranja) será el color del `select`:

```
onchange="this.style.color=this.value"
```

Tu código sería el siguiente:

```css
body {
  padding: 0 24px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="color" class="col-form-label font-weight-bold">Color:</label>                   
  <select class="form-control fa" onchange="this.style.color=this.value" name="color" id="color" required>
    <option value="">Seleccionar</option>
    <option class="fa" style="color:#0071c5;" value="#0071c5">&#xf0c8; Azul Oscuro</option>
    <option class="fa" style="color:#40E0D0;" value="#40E0D0">&#xf0c8; Turquesa</option>
    <option class="fa" style="color:#008000;" value="#008000">&#xf0c8; Verde</option>
    <option class="fa" style="color:#FFD700;" value="#FFD700">&#xf0c8; Amarillo</option>
    <option class="fa" style="color:#FF8C00;" value="#FF8C00">&#xf0c8; Naranja</option>
    <option class="fa" style="color:#FF0000;" value="#FF0000">&#xf0c8; Rojo</option>
    <option class="fa" style="color:#000000;" value="#000000">&#xf0c8; Negro</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda me soluciono el problema ahora si puedo seleccionar un color y ver el icono en el select de ese color pero el problema ahora es que me ha cambiado el font a otro estilo como podria resolver ello??